# How to hide "Cond" tensors in Tensorboard? (with a screenshot)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

In Tensorboard, my network graph appears nicely except that there are so many `cond` tensors (eg., `cond`, `cond_1`, `cond_2`, ..., `cond_204`). Since they are too many, they shrink everything, which is very inconvenient.

Note that they are not convolution tensors `conv` but conditional tensors `cond`. I guess they are introduced due to my `rmsprop` optimizer (ExponentialMovingAverage?). Is there a way that I can hide them in Tensorboard?

[image: Tensorboard]

Answer (score 2):

If you find which part of your code is generating all these conds, you can hide them in a name scope like this:

```
with tf.name_scope("hide_all_conds"):
   call_code_that_creates_many_conds()
```

Then all of the conds will be grouped into a single block, which you can expand or collapse.